# How can I create a Lightroom Smart Collection with multiple and/or conditions?

Tags: lightroom, keywords, smart-collections

I'm having trouble getting the right pictures in the smart collection based on my conditions...perhaps you can help.

Tags:

> Bananas
>
> Oranges
>
> Apples
>
> Pears

Show me all Bananas and Show me all Oranges, but only if either of them contain either Apples or Pears.

Very confusing.  I keep getting either too many images, or zero images.

Comment: Hi Jon, interesting question, I can imagine it's a bit of a head scratcher. Would you mind sharing what you've tried so far? I. e. what conditions gave you too many or zero images?

Comment: I have no solution to the technical issue.  But as far as the logic is concerned, the baskets with bananas and oranges shouldn't contain any apples or pears, so the result should be zero.

Comment: The logic is ((B&&(A||P) || (O&&(A||P)) but I've no clue how to translate that for Lr.

Comment: "*How can I create a Lightroom Smart Collection with multiple and/or conditions?*"  ??-   Is it quicker to Los Angles or by plane?

Comment: Lol...what's longer?  A rope?

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

I think I found the correct rules:

[image]

The trick is in creating two subgroups, one for **bananas** and one for **oranges** and then creating sub-subgroups for those two subgroups.

You can get subgroups by holding <kbd>alt</kbd> (on a Mac) and then clicking the plus sign `+` (which turns into a pound sign `#` when holding <kbd>alt</kbd>).
This creates a new subrule, allowing you to set the **All/Any of the following are true** dropdown for that subgroup only.

## Importing rules

I've exported the smart collection rules [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/hTcQHN73).
To get that back in your LR as a smart collection, follow these steps:

1. Copy the text from the link into a text file
2. Change the extension from `.txt` to `.lrsmcol`
3. In LR, right click in the **Collections** panel and click **Import Smart Collection Settings...**.

[image]

4. Select the `.lrsmcol` file from step 2.

This should re-create the smart collection shown in the top screenshot.

Comment: Yup, that's the practical translation of my logic comment above. Nice find.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give it a go.